# Using an extension method on a dictionary

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am not sure how to use an extension method on a dictionary. How do I specify that I need the function applied to the value and not the key?

Here's a sample code applying the Sum extension method on a list of doubles and a dictionary whose values are doubles. The list extension methods works fine but the dictionary extension method is asking for a selector function.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<double> list = new List<double>();
        list.Add(34.2);
        list.Add(234);
        Console.WriteLine(list.Sum());

        Dictionary<string, double> dictioanary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        dictioanary.Add("a", 5.34);
        dictioanary.Add("b", 44);

        Console.WriteLine(dictioanary.Sum());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a lambda to the Sum() function:

```
Console.WriteLine(dictioanary.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dictionary's `Values` collection.

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this:

```
public static int MyExtension<valueType,keyType>(this Dictionary<valueType,keyType> dict )
{
  return dict.Values.Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary's `Values` property is a `ICollection<T>`. ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx))  Instead of writing your own extension method, you should use Linq's extensions.

```
using System.Linq;

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<double> list = new List<double>();
        list.Add(34.2);
        list.Add(234);
        Console.WriteLine(list.Sum());

        Dictionary<string, double> dictioanary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        dictioanary.Add("a", 5.34);
        dictioanary.Add("b", 44);

        Console.WriteLine(dictioanary.Values.Sum()); // See?
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```